# Casual usage of i-adjectives and ending particles

Tags: colloquial-language, i-adjectives

In Real casual japanese one may hear

> 明日のテストってこわ。。。

I am wondering, how often this level of 'casualness' happens.

Can I add sentence ending particles, even though there is an い omitted (and です). For example:

> ゆきは走るのがはやね。

I omitted the whole structure, but still added ね to emphasize, that Yuki runs fust, doesn't he?

However this is pretty standard, for a plain form, am I right?

> おもしろいね

If a similar question has been answered somewhere, please link it for me, and also I'm not sure if my question is phrased correctly, I hope it's understandable.

Comment: What's happening is a softening of the final い, as a kind of contraction.  Depending on the term, final particles can appear after such contractions: 分からんぞ, for instance.  In casual speech, the final vowel may also change (technically called "monophthongization", as the "diphthong" or two-vowel sound fuses into a single-vowel sound): はやい may sound like _hayee_, すごい may sound like _sugee_, おもしろい may sound like _omoshiree_.

Comment: See user4092's answer below for a better explanation of い-deletion in interjectionary uses, as opposed to monophthongization.

Answer (score 2):

ゆきは走るのがはやね is impossible.

Those stand alone stems of i-adjective are not so much a casual form as a kind of interjection you use when you are surprised and it doesn't allow any grammatical elements to follow. In addition, it's different from collapse of diphthongs.

Answer (score 0):

There are several patterns for adjectives in casual speech:

One is that the end of the adjective changes to an "e" vowel, like おもしれー, はえー, おせー, こえー, いてー.

One is that the end of the adjective changes to an "i" vowel, like さみー,あちー,ねみー, かいー.

One is that the end of the adjective is omitted, like さむっ, あつっ, くさっ.

Some particles like な, よ, か can be added to them (except for in the omitted ones), like おもしれーな, ねみーよ, さみーか but ね isn't usually added to them.